# Flutter run Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I just installed the flutter sdk and android studio to learn flutter but I cant run my app in the mobile emulator. I managed to make it work in normal chrome but not the emulator and I dont know why. Here is the console output when I run flutter run -v:

```
[ +729 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +27 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LegacyCanvasKitRemover' is not required, skipping update.
[  +26 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +512 ms] executing: C:\Users\julian.runge\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[ +395 ms] List of devices attached
                    emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone64_x86_64 model:sdk_gphone64_x86_64 device:emu64xa transport_id:1
[  +57 ms] C:\Users\julian.runge\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell getprop
[ +449 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +49 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +6 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +5 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +596 ms] Skipping pub get: version match.
[ +847 ms] Generating C:\Users\julian.runge\Desktop\Learning\Dart & Flutter\fluttergrundlagen\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[ +235 ms] ro.hardware = ranchu
[ +674 ms] No packages with native assets. Skipping native assets compilation.
[  +46 ms] Initializing file store
[ +145 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[  +91 ms] gen_dart_plugin_registrant: Starting due to {InvalidatedReasonKind.inputChanged: The following inputs have updated contents: C:\Users\julian.runge\Desktop\Learning\Dart &
Flutter\fluttergrundlagen\.dart_tool\package_config_subset}
[ +489 ms] gen_dart_plugin_registrant: Complete
[  +17 ms] Skipping target: _composite
[  +22 ms] complete
[  +42 ms] Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
[  +15 ms] C:\tools\flutter-sdk\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dartaotruntime.exe --disable-dart-dev C:\tools\flutter-sdk\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\snapshots\frontend_server_aot.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
C:\tools\flutter-sdk\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter --experimental-emit-debug-metadata -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true
-DFLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=https://www.gstatic.com/flutter-canvaskit/04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed/ --output-dill C:\Users\JULIAN~1.RUN\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.57c8b058\flutter_tool.751309b1\app.dill --packages  
C:\Users\julian.runge\Desktop\Learning\Dart & Flutter\fluttergrundlagen\.dart_tool\package_config.json -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root    
--initialize-from-dill build\f4da31578bf74e160393d588ebd02ee2.cache.dill.track.dill --verbosity=error --enable-experiment=alternative-invalidation-strategy
[ +113 ms] executing: C:\Users\julian.runge\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[ +678 ms] <- compile package:fluttergrundlagen/main.dart
[ +603 ms] --------- beginning of main
                    02-16 14:59:16.732 D/StatusBarIconController(  928): ignoring old pipeline callback because the new wifi icon is enabled
[  +30 ms] executing: C:\Users\julian.runge\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[ +191 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
                    Version 34.0.5-10900879
                    Installed as C:\Users\julian.runge\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
                    Running on Windows 10.0.22631
[   +8 ms] executing: C:\Users\julian.runge\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[ +237 ms] Building APK
[  +47 ms] executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[ +838 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[   +1 ms] openjdk version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314, mixed mode)
[  +45 ms] executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java --version
[ +561 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java --version
[   +2 ms] openjdk 17.0.7 2023-04-18
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314, mixed mode)
[ +120 ms] Using gradle from C:\Users\julian.runge\Desktop\Learning\Dart & Flutter\fluttergrundlagen\android\gradlew.bat.
[   +5 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[  +27 ms] executing: [C:\Users\julian.runge\Desktop\Learning\Dart & Flutter\fluttergrundlagen\android/] C:\Users\julian.runge\Desktop\Learning\Dart & Flutter\fluttergrundlagen\android\gradlew.bat --full-stacktrace --info
-Pverbose=true -Ptarget-platform=android-x64 -Ptarget=C:\Users\julian.runge\Desktop\Learning\Dart & Flutter\fluttergrundlagen\lib\main.dart -Pbase-application-name=android.app.Application
-Pdart-defines=RkxVVFRFUl9XRUJfQVVUT19ERVRFQ1Q9dHJ1ZQ==,RkxVVFRFUl9XRUJfQ0FOVkFTS0lUX1VSTD1odHRwczovL3d3dy5nc3RhdGljLmNvbS9mbHV0dGVyLWNhbnZhc2tpdC8wNDgxN2M5OWM5ZmQ0OTU2ZjI3NTA1MjA0ZjdlMzQ0MzM1ODEwYWVkLw== -Pdart-obfuscation=false    
-Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Ptree-shake-icons=false -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
[ +364 ms] Der Befehl "Flutter\fluttergrundlagen\android\" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
[   +8 ms] konnte nicht gefunden werden.
[ +792 ms] Fehler: Hauptklasse org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
[   +2 ms] Ursache: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
[ +119 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 1.277ms)
[+16534 ms] Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[  +15 ms] "flutter run" took 26.325ms.
[ +174 ms] 
                    #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
                    #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:811:9)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1389:27)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:355:9)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:295:5)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:119:9)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
                    <asynchronous suspension>


[ +174 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 156ms
[   +2 ms] Running 1 shutdown hook
[  +18 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[  +14 ms] exiting with code 1
```

Before anyone is answering "Its because there are whitespaces in the path" it also doesnt work when the whitespaces are gone and it also shows a different error in the console. Here is the same console log without the whitespaces in the path:

```
[+1657 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +26 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LegacyCanvasKitRemover' is not required, skipping update.
[  +16 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +6 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +5 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +339 ms] executing: C:\Users\julian.runge\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[ +597 ms] List of devices attached
                    emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone64_x86_64 model:sdk_gphone64_x86_64 device:emu64xa transport_id:1
[ +119 ms] C:\Users\julian.runge\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell getprop
[ +995 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +34 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +845 ms] Skipping pub get: version match.
[ +791 ms] Generating C:\Users\julian.runge\Desktop\Learning\Dart&Flutter\fluttergrundlagen\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[ +277 ms] ro.hardware = ranchu
[ +718 ms] No packages with native assets. Skipping native assets compilation.
[  +18 ms] Initializing file store
[  +56 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[  +33 ms] gen_dart_plugin_registrant: Starting due to {InvalidatedReasonKind.inputChanged: The following inputs have updated contents:
C:\Users\julian.runge\Desktop\Learning\Dart&Flutter\fluttergrundlagen\.dart_tool\package_config_subset}
[ +403 ms] gen_dart_plugin_registrant: Complete
[  +11 ms] Skipping target: _composite
[   +9 ms] complete
[  +50 ms] Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
[  +38 ms] C:\tools\flutter-sdk\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dartaotruntime.exe --disable-dart-dev C:\tools\flutter-sdk\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\snapshots\frontend_server_aot.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
C:\tools\flutter-sdk\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter --experimental-emit-debug-metadata -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true
-DFLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=https://www.gstatic.com/flutter-canvaskit/04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed/ --output-dill C:\Users\JULIAN~1.RUN\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.85b632cc\flutter_tool.c95569ec\app.dill --packages  
C:\Users\julian.runge\Desktop\Learning\Dart&Flutter\fluttergrundlagen\.dart_tool\package_config.json -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root      
--initialize-from-dill build\f4da31578bf74e160393d588ebd02ee2.cache.dill.track.dill --verbosity=error --enable-experiment=alternative-invalidation-strategy
[ +135 ms] executing: C:\Users\julian.runge\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +58 ms] <- compile package:fluttergrundlagen/main.dart
[+1081 ms] --------- beginning of system
                    02-16 15:09:45.056 W/SystemServiceManager(  637): Service com.android.server.usage.StorageStatsService$Lifecycle took 62 ms in onBootPhase
[  +32 ms] executing: C:\Users\julian.runge\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[ +283 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
                    Version 34.0.5-10900879
                    Installed as C:\Users\julian.runge\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
                    Running on Windows 10.0.22631
[   +8 ms] executing: C:\Users\julian.runge\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[ +349 ms] Building APK
[  +85 ms] executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[+1250 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[   +2 ms] openjdk version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314, mixed mode)
[  +60 ms] executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java --version
[+1195 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java --version
[   +1 ms] openjdk 17.0.7 2023-04-18
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314, mixed mode)
[ +146 ms] Using gradle from C:\Users\julian.runge\Desktop\Learning\Dart&Flutter\fluttergrundlagen\android\gradlew.bat.
[  +13 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[ +108 ms] executing: [C:\Users\julian.runge\Desktop\Learning\Dart&Flutter\fluttergrundlagen\android/] C:\Users\julian.runge\Desktop\Learning\Dart&Flutter\fluttergrundlagen\android\gradlew.bat --full-stacktrace --info -Pverbose=true
-Ptarget-platform=android-x64 -Ptarget=C:\Users\julian.runge\Desktop\Learning\Dart&Flutter\fluttergrundlagen\lib\main.dart -Pbase-application-name=android.app.Application
-Pdart-defines=RkxVVFRFUl9XRUJfQVVUT19ERVRFQ1Q9dHJ1ZQ==,RkxVVFRFUl9XRUJfQ0FOVkFTS0lUX1VSTD1odHRwczovL3d3dy5nc3RhdGljLmNvbS9mbHV0dGVyLWNhbnZhc2tpdC8wNDgxN2M5OWM5ZmQ0OTU2ZjI3NTA1MjA0ZjdlMzQ0MzM1ODEwYWVkLw== -Pdart-obfuscation=false    
-Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Ptree-shake-icons=false -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
[ +884 ms] Der Befehl "C:\Users\julian.runge\Desktop\Learning\Dart" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
[  +16 ms] konnte nicht gefunden werden.
[  +26 ms] Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
[  +20 ms] Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
[ +137 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 1.074ms)
[+27314 ms] Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[  +19 ms] "flutter run" took 38.839ms.
[ +156 ms] 
                    #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
                    #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:811:9)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1389:27)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:355:9)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:295:5)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:119:9)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
                    <asynchronous suspension>


[ +201 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 159ms
[   +6 ms] Running 1 shutdown hook
[  +35 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[  +65 ms] exiting with code 1
```

When using flutter doctor it says no issues were found.

Comment: try renaming your "Dart&Flutter" folder with "DartAndFlutter"